# unable to post out email from gnus - "make client process failed"

Tags: gnus

I have a major problem with gnus, running on debian testing in that I am now *totally* unable to send any email out, and it even survives a reboot! When I try to send an email the following comes up in the debugger -

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "make client process failed" "connection refused" :name "smtpmail" :buffer #<buffer *trace of SMTP session to london*> :host "london" :service 25)
  make-network-process(:name "smtpmail" :buffer #<buffer *trace of SMTP session to london*> :host "london" :service 25)
  network-stream-open-starttls("smtpmail" #<buffer *trace of SMTP session to london*> "london" 25 (:type plain :return-list t :capability-command "EHLO london.london
\n" :end-of-command "^[0-9]+ .*
\n" :success "^2.*\n" :always-query-capabilities t :starttls-function #[(capabilities) "\301\302\"\205
```

There is a lot more but I'm unable to post it all. I've tried also at http://paste.debian.net/163455/ but theres not a lot of difference.

How do I get round it please to stop me being locked out of sending emails?

This is part of my gnus-file -

```
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "relay.plus.net")
(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
(require 'smtpmail)
(require 'expiry-hack)

(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials "~/.authinfo")

(setq starttls-use-gnutls t
      starttls-gnutls-program "gnutls-cli")
```

And when checked gnutls-cli is provided by `gnutils-bin` which wasn't installed, but now is. So I'll reboot and see if that sorts the problem out.

Comment: What is `sendmail-program` set to?  Are you using an external SMTP client (e.g. msmtp)?  What are your mail-related settings?  I for one just use an externally configured msmtp and have `(setq sendmail-program "/usr/bin/msmtp")` set.

Comment: This looks like a network problem. Try running `telnet london 25` in a terminal, and you'll probably get the same result.

Comment: It just comes back with `connection refused` even with sudo tried as well!